# Angular bug or misunderstanding of JS inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I'm having trouble with a nested control becoming disconnected from a variable it's bound to.

I've tracked it down to these lines in `ngModelController` in the angular source:

The stack trace enters during `$$writeModelToScope` and calls a setter function (in parser helper module):

```
key = ensureSafeMemberName(element.shift(), fullExp);
ensureSafeObject(obj[key], fullExp);
obj[key] = setValue;
return setValue;
```

The scope at the time is on a child directive which requires a parent ng-model controller. I can see that the scope has inherited the parent scope and my property is present.

The `key` is my property name and when the expression `obj[key]` is evaluated in the debugger, it shows the value before modification which is correct.

As soon as the expression `obj[key] = setValue` is evaluated, a property is created on the child scope which hides the parent property and therefore disconnects the binding.

My question is, why does this expression not set the value on the parent instead of creating a new property on the child object?

From what I've read, this is by design, writing always writes to the target object, is that correct? If so the only way I can think of addressing this is to watch for the property change on the child scope and push the value onto the parent scope...

Comment: Although the exact use case is not clear, generally yes, this is how prototypical inheritance works. The solution to your problem *may* be to add the value you pass to `ng-model` in another objects, i.e. instead of `ng-model="myvalue"`, do `ng-model="wrapper.myvalue"`.

Comment: Ok, looks like javascript writes never lookup - they always write to the target object. The fix seems to be to watch the scope for changes and push the write up to the parent... will try that - either that or using a $parent prefix on the property (though I'd rather avoid this as it complicates the usage of the wrapper)

Comment: Actually that was much simpler than I thought it would be! Thanks for the tip Nikos, I just added the $parent prefix to the bindings in the wrappers directive and they resolve correctly!

Comment: The `$parent` was exactly the thing I was trying to avoid with the wrapper :) In *some* cases, it does make sense, in *many* cases it is a source of unmaintenable code! Tread lightly :)